# Run jenkins job periodically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to execute a `python script` once in a day at say 1 PM.

I tried using * 13 * * * but the script did not execute automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the Build periodically option as below:

```
H(0-6) ****
```

you should use the  hours option **** means every day in every week of every month of every year during 0-6 hours this worked perfectly for me

Answer :

```
 H(0-10) 13 * * *
```

Comment: didn't you mean every hour in the first 7 minutes?

Comment: @esissay , According to the cron ,yes it will run every hour in the first 7 minutes, but my answer was to advise him to use "H" (hash) in cron expression , so that jenkins will have the breathing time to build the job in the time range. Thanks Update the cron expression now :)

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it didn't execute? Normally it will send a mail to the user account authorised to run the script - look under /var/mail/$ACCOUNT and you should see if it ran, but failed...

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to run the build at 1 PM every day. You can use the below in this case and try.

`0 13 1-31 1-12 0-7`